# React app is not launching upon 'npm start' in command line. npm install commands aren't responding too in cmd

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have waited for 30-40 minutes leaving the command line prompt as it is. But it isn't launching any react apps. I don't have any unused import statement, I haven't made any such changes in files too.
It generally used to launch within a minute. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Sorry to be that guy....but have you tried exiting the application and running again?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html Follow these instructions

Comment: Was it created using create-react-app? How much RAM does your setup have? Have you tried removing your node_modules, installing again and trying?

Comment: Yes it was created using create-react-myapp . 8GB RAM, Other non react apps are launching in localhost using nodemon command. I have tried exiting the application but it shows the same thing. I read about .npmrc file as well but I don't have it in Users folder in Windows.